# Setting a cookie's value to a template literal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I'm creating a template literal like so:

```
const someVar = 'hello'    

const str = `
  Some random
  multiline string with string interpolation: ${someVar}
`
```

And then in my Koa app, I'm doing:

```
this.cookies.set('str', str)
```

Apparently it doesn't like the multiline string, as it gives this error:

> TypeError: argument value is invalid

Is there any way around this? Keeping the whitespace format is pretty necessary in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the template literal; by the time you're getting the error, you have a string with newlines in it. You can't have newlines in a cookie value.

Probably the best thing to preserve those newlines is to use JSON:

```
this.cookies.set('str', JSON.stringify(str));
```

Of course, you'll need to `JSON.parse` it when using it.

You don't have to use JSON, of course; you could use URI-encoding:

```
this.cookies.set('str', encodeURIComponent(str));
```

...and then decode it with `decodeURIComponent` (or the equivalent for whatever's consuming the string).

Comment: Ah for some reason I thought `JSON.parse` always parsed a string as an object/array literal. I was very wrong on that, thanks a lot!

Comment: @saadq: There's a reason you thought that. :-) The early version of the JSON spec did indeed require that the top level be an object or array. But fairly early on it became clear that allowing any valid JSON value was more useful, and that's what made it into the JavaScript spec (and the JSON spec in the end). It's been years, but the idea that the top level had to be an object or array got established in people's thinking and you'll still find people saying it...